# Show Deal only if its starting from todays date

Tags: date

I am working on a daily deal module. The module lists all the deals that are active and have start and end date.

For ex:

```
Deal One:
Start Date : 31 JULY
End Date : 5 AUG

Deal Two:
Start Date : 3 AUG
End Date : 5 AUG
```

Here you can see that `Deal One` has started `yesterday`, while `Deal Two` will start on `3 AUG`

The date format displayed in array is like below for a deal

```
[start_date] => 2014-03-06 00:00:00
[end_date] => 2014-05-19 00:00:00
```

How can I show a deal that will start only from today's date and remain active till its `end date`, i.e. if a deal has future start date, it won't appear in deal list and will be only shown when its start date matches with today's or current date ?

Multiple deals will be shown on deal listing page.

Will it conflict if I change my system date and time ?

Please Help.

Thanks

Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method I've used for something quite similar (in this case, using the "Special Price" date range for the product).

I've extended from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`

```
protected function _saleList()
{
parent::_construct();
$this->setTemplate('saleitems.phtml');

// This should get the time localized to your timezone setting
$timestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
$this->_today = date('m/d/y h:i:s', $timestamp);

// I've set these as class properties, but you could just use a plain old variable if you like. I don't use these here but use them for listing upcoming and expired items.
$this->_tomorrow = date('m/d/y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') + 1, date('y')));
$this->_oneWeek = date('m/d/y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') + 7, date('y')));
$this->_yesterday = date('m/d/y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 1, date('y')));


// Here's the important bit. Note the `from` and `to` arguments passed in the array when filtering the dates. `to` is essentially a <=, and `from` is >= and they are used for dates.
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $this->_today))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('date' => true, 'from' => $this->_today))
    ->addAttributeToSort('special_to_date', 'asc');

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

// In your template, you can call $this->getSaleItems() and then iterate over each
$this->setSaleItems($collection);
}
```

Comment: A deal will be seen only when it matches the start date and current date and will expire only when the current date is less than end date

Comment: Yes, see where dates are filtered in the collection. This would filter products that have a `special_from_date` (start date) that is less than or equal to today and has a `special_to_date` (end date) that is greater than or equal to today.

Comment: I am no using any collection. Could you pls post that in simple code

Comment: I shared this because it is something I've already written and thought it might be useful to you. I don't know what "simple code" is so I cannot help you there.

Comment: Could you pls let me know the difference between `addFieldToFilter('start_date',array('lteq'=>$todayDate))` and `addFieldToFilter('start_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))` ??

Comment: See: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento    -- `from` and `to` are used for dates. I think they are basically the same, but it allows for the `date` or `datetime` arguments to be passed.

Comment: please check [daily deals](https://www.mageants.com/daily-deals-extension-for-magento-2.html) extension of mageants it will help you to support for installation and issues